# generate a Firebase Cloud Function for each Firebase user in the database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to  to have a Firebase Cloud Function that do some mathematical equation to my user  information that is stored on my database, I want it to be triggered  when a user update his information. How I can get a database reference to all my child nodes in the data base . is there a way to generate a function when a user is created which will be triggered with his database reference that way i will have a function for each user created?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide your coded attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look a this official sample https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users which implements an example of the `functions.auth.user().onCreate((user))` trigger

Comment: `I want it to be triggered when a user update `then generate a function when a user is created`,which one of the two is the question